# iframe content doesn't always load

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

So I have a system that essentially enabled communication between two computers, and uses a WebRTC framework to achieve this:

"The Host": This is the control computer, and clients connect to this. They control the clients window.
"The Client": The is the user on the other end. They are having their window controlled by the server.

What I mean by control, is that the host can:

- change CSS on the clients open window.
- control the URL of an iframe on the clients open window

There are variations on these but essentially thats the amount of control there is.

When "the client" logs in, the host sends a web address to the client. This web address will then be displayed in an iframe, as such:

```
$('#iframe_id').attr("src", URL);
```

there is also the ability to send a new web address to the client, in the form of a message. The same code is used above in order to navigate to that URL.

The problem I am having is that on, roughly 1 in 4 computers the iframe doesn't actually load. It either displays a white screen, or it shows the little "page could not be displayed" icon:

- I have been unable to reliably duplicate this bug
- I have not seen a clear pattern between computers that can and cannot view the iframe content.

All clients are running google chrome, most on an apple powermac. The only semi-link I have made is that windows computers seem slightly more susceptible to it, but not in a way I can reproduce. Sometimes refreshing the page works...

Are there any known bugs that could possibly cause this to happen? I have read about iframe white flashes but I am confident it isn't that issue. I am confident it isn't a problem with jQuery loading because that produces issues before this and would be easy to spot.

Thanks so much.
Alex

edit: Ok so here is the code that is collecting data from the server. Upon inspection the data being received is correct.

```
conn.on('data', function(data) {
    var data_array = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(data_array);

    // initialisation
    if(data_array.type=='init' && inititated === false) {
        if(data_array.duration  > 0) {
            set_timeleft(data_array.duration);                  // how long is the exam? (minutes)      
        } else {
            $('#connection_remainingtime').html('No limits');
        }
        $('#content_frame').attr("src", data_array.uri);    // url to navigate to
        //timestarted = data_array.start.replace(/ /g,'');  // start time
        ob = data_array.ob;                                 // is it open book? Doesnt do anything really... why use it if it isnt open book?
        snd = data_array.snd;                               // is sound allowed?
        inititated = true;
    }       
}
```

It is definitele trying to make the iframe navigate somewhere as when the client launches the iframe changes - its trying to load something but failing.

**EDIT: Update on this issue:** It does actually work, just not with google forms. And again it isn't everybody's computers, it is only a few people. If they navigate elsewhere (http://www.bit-tech.net for example) then it works just fine.

** FURTHER UPDATE **: It seems on the ones that fail, there is an 'X-Frames-Origin' issue, in that its set the 'SAMEORIGIN'. I dont understand why some students would get this problem and some wouldn't... surely it depends upon the page you are navigating to, and if one person can get it all should be able to?

Comment: This depends on what JS/jQ you got loading on client and on host (which you haven't provided)

Comment: Hmm, the version loading on the client I guess is the same as the version I have (I dont load from the CDN). Its jQuery v2.1.4. Might it use a cached version from another site and that is causing the problems?

Comment: No I mean we have no idea what the code is or what it's doing. Make a [MCVE (**M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). `$('#iframe_id').attr("src", URL);` is not enough.

Comment: Ah I see, ok. i have added an edit onto my first post to see if that helps. It is certainly getting to the part where it tries to redirect the iframe, but the iframe is not managing to load the page - despite it appearing to try.

Comment: Update on this issue: It does actually work, just not with google forms. And again it isn't everybody's computers, it is only a few people. If they navigate elsewhere (http://www.bit-tech.net for example) then it works just fine.

Comment: ** FURTHER UPDATE **: It seems on the ones that fail, there is an 'X-Frames-Origin' issue, in that its set the 'SAMEORIGIN'. I dont understand why some students would get this problem and some wouldn't... surely it depends upon the page you are navigating to, and if one person can get it all should be able to?

Answer (score 1):

So the problem here was that the students were trying to load this behind a proxy server which has an issue with cookies. Although the site does not use cookies, the proxy does, and when the student had blocked "third party cookies" in their settings then the proxy was not allowing the site to load.

Simply allowed cookies and it worked :)

Comment: In the future maybe give the students a guide as to what they should have prepared before they start an exercise. Like enabling cookies and JavaScript (for people stuck in the 90s). Upped for thoroughness.

Comment: I intend to, however as I didn't use cookies this wasn't a problem I had anticipated. Interestingly it seems to be a connection between google forms and the proxy servers, as other sites work without cookies enabled. Maybe google forms doesn't allow iframe access if you dont have cookies enabled?

Answer (score 0):

iframes are one of the last things to load in the DOM, so wrap your iframe dependent code in this:

```
document.getElementById('content_frame').onload = function() {...}
```

If that doesn't work then it's the document within the iframe. If you own the page inside the iframe then you have options. If not...`setTimeout`? Or `window.onload`...?

### SNIPPET

```js
conn.on('data', function(data) {
      var data_array = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(data_array);

      // initialisation
      if (data_array.type == 'init' && inititated === false) {
        if (data_array.duration > 0) {
          set_timeleft(data_array.duration); // how long is the exam? (minutes)      
        } else {
          $('#connection_remainingtime').html('No limits');
        }
        document.getElementById('content_frame').onload = function() {
          $('#content_frame').attr("src", data_array.uri); // url to navigate to
          //timestarted = data_array.start.replace(/ /g,'');  // start time
          ob = data_array.ob; // is it open book? Doesnt do anything really... why use it if it isnt open book?
          snd = data_array.snd; // is sound allowed?
          inititated = true;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry it took some time to get back to you - I needed a specific situation to test this. Sadly it doesn't work, this just always leaves the iframe as a white page (the src attribute reads as "localhost" throughout). The iframe has lots of time to load too (its hidden in the background whilst you log in) so I am sceptical about that being the issue.